# Partial Postback ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, delphi

I have a ASP.NET 1.1 web application page which is built with .net framework 1.1 and in GridView the data is displayed.

I want when they select multiple items then data is updated but without the complete postback of the page. Any help or suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the gridview in an asp:UpdatePanel

See example here: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Best way to implement this in your scenario is write the code assuming you will do a full postback (ie on checkbox click, wire up a server event handler).

Once its all working with full postback, wrap the gridview in an UpdatePanel to achieve the partial postback.

Comment: But how will the web application understand asp:UpdatePanel? it's .net 1.1

Comment: OK In this case, you cant use the server control (only 2.0 and greater).

You'll have to use the client-side AJAX library.

See example here: http://dflying.dflying.net/1/archive/96_introduction_to_atlas_updatepanel.html

Here is another approach using "traditional ajax":
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050526.htm